# Where to adjust number of returned results on the /admin/people page? I know, don't hack core

Tags: 7, users

I know, you don't need to tell me. **Don't Hack Core** but I just need to display 1000 user records rows on the /admin/people page **temporarily** and I'll switch it back. I promise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [Admininstration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module; it converts that page to a View, which you can edit and set up with paging of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Goto /modules/user/user.admin.inc and search for limit and change the 50 to whatever number you like.